# Java path error while installing glass fish 3.1.2

Tags: glassfish-3

I installed JDK 7 update 5 (64 bit) on my server(Server has 64 bit windows OS). Set the environment path. When i do **java -version**. I get the output `java version 1.7_0_05` but when i try to install glass fish then i get the error that `This application needs version 1.6 or higher of the Java (TM)2 Runtime Environment` . I have set both the JDK bin folder and JRE bin folder on my environment path. Why i am getting this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 24):

I didn't update the environment variable but i think path should be to JRE that is inside JDK like i tried this and it worked

`D:\Basit>ogs-3.1.2-windows.exe -j "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre"`.

Hope this answer will help others also.

Comment: I had to do it this way too, but there does seem to be something not quite right with the installer. I can't get it to read my environment variables no matter how I set them

Comment: For me, I pointed to the jdk directory and not the jre directory and everything went smoothly.

Comment: if when using asadmin commands, you face "The system cannot find the path specified.", then seems that glassfish\config\asenv.bat is not configured correctly, so edit by setting
`set AS_JAVA=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre`
(see https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/16155)

Answer (score 5):

1. Open cmd make sure you cd to the path of you glassfish installation file :cd C:\Users\John\Downloads
2. locate your jre file which should be in your jdk1.7x : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre
3. In the cmd paste this : glassfish-3.1.2.2-windows.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre"

make sure you have the correct version

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was a blank space in "Program Files" (Yes I have JAVA_HOME set) You can run installation from cmd with argumentation (do not forget quotation) -j "c:/.../java path" Example from my case:

> c:\Users\Kryst\Downloads>glassfish-4.0-web-windows.exe -j "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_ 79\jre"

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

- Java Version > Java v1.6
- Open downloaded folder and select
  shift+right-click+open-command-window-here
- Type exact file name of downloaded file -j and JRE path

in my case

- ogs-3.1.2.2-windows.exe -j "c:\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre

Comment: note: make sure java version and path should be correct
and press Enter

Answer (score 0):

Try setting JAVA_HOME environment variable to the JDK root folder.

Comment: how can i set JAVA_HOME? I added the `;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;` in the **path** `System variable`

Answer (score 0):

or just download a bundle package such as http://netbeans.org/downloads/ and click on the Java EE or ALL catagory